# How to rewrite this R code in cycle form?(about randomly choose the variables)

Tags: r

everyone.   I need to use `nlme` to do data analysis. Please see the below code. All the other parameters are the same. The only difference is in random=list()  part. Here we randomly choose parameters from `a0,a1,a2,a3,b0,c0,c1,c2,c3` and combine them together. That is `random=list(SJ=(a0~1)),random=list(SJ=(a1~1)),...,random=list(SJ=(a0+a1~1)),...,random=list(SJ=(a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1)).` How to rewrite it as a cycling form?  Thanks a lot!

```
C1 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a0~1)))
C2 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a1~1)))
C3 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a2~1)))
C4 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a3~1)))
C5 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(b0~1)))
C6 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(c0~1)))
C7 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(c1~1)))
C8 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(c2~1)))
C9 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(c3~1)))
C10 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a0+a1~1)))
C11 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a0+a2~1)))
C12 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a0+a3~1))
C13 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a0+b0~1)))
C14 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a0+c0~1)))
C15 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a0+c1~1)))
C16 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a0+c2~1)))
C17 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a0+c3~1)))
C18 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a1+a2~1)))
C19 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a1+a3~1)))


C511 <- nlme(YC~(a0+a1*ppc1+a2*ppc2+a3*ppc3)/(1+(b0)*exp(-(c0+c1*ppc1+c2*ppc2+c3*ppc3)*T)),data=list(YC=datajieximu$CZS,T=datajieximu$A,ppc1=datapastxin$pc1,ppc2=datapastxin$pc2,ppc3=datapastxin$pc3),fixed=a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1,random=list(SJ=(a0+a1+a2+a3+b0+c0+c1+c2+c3~1)),control = nlmeControl(maxIter=100))
```

Comment: You can store fomulas in a vector, it could be generated with `as.formula` and `combn`. Then loop over all your formulas.

Comment: how to rewrite the C1,C2,~C511 using cycling , do I need  to use 'paste'?

Comment: Look at nicola's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#vector with the names of the variables
vars <- c("a0", "a1", "a2", "a3", "b0", "c0", "c1", "c2", "c3")
#we build the "power set" of vars:
ps <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(vars), combn, 
                    x=vars, simplify=FALSE) ,recursive=FALSE)
#For each element in ps we build a named list with the SJ element which is a formula
formulas <- lapply(ps, function(x) 
                        list(SJ=as.formula(paste(paste(x, collapse="+"), "~1"))))
```

Then you can loop/lapply over `formulas` and call your line.